# How to display images of a Venue listing using UICollectionView within a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a `UIIMageView` within a `UICollectionViewCell`.

The `UICollectionView` is within a `UITableViewCell` and I would like to display all the images (held within a URL string array carousel style) for the particular `Venue` within the `UITableViewCell`.

Here is my `tableView` `cellForRowAt` which displays the `Venues` perfectly fine.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VenueListingCell", for: indexPath) as? VenueListingCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let venueCurrent = filteredVenueArray[indexPath.row]

    venueLoaded = venueCurrent //copy into var to be used in collectionView

    cell.configureCell(venue: venueCurrent) 

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell 
}
```

Here is my `CollectionView` `cellForItemAt` function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VenueListingCellImage", for: indexPath) as! VenueListingCellImage

    let imgURL = URL(string: (venueLoaded?.imgURLs[indexPath.row])!)

    cell.configureCell(url: imgURL!)

    return cell
}
```

PROBLEM:

**How do I ensure that I use the correct Venue's images within the UICollectionView?**

Comment: your CollectionView cellForItemAt is within UITableViewCell, am I right?

Comment: correct. Just to be clear, my data set is made up of an array of type Venue (filteredVenueArray ) and each Venue contains an array of type String (imgURLs) which I wish to load for each Venue in a carousel style.

Comment: Why are you using venueLoaded?

Comment: this is where I'm stuck, I figured that I would save the Venue from the cell into venueLoaded so I can use to get to the imgURLs to display the images but its not working.

Comment: are you done with the solution?

Comment: no, the proposed solution deviates from the MVC model approach I think. I am currently researching to see how to best keep in line with the MVC model using the approach as details here [https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/]

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm providing you the scenario, how to implement `UICollectionView` inside `VenueListingCell`.

First of all, in your create you should create your `Venue` object in `VenueListingCell` custom class.

Now you have your `venue` object for each indexPath of `VenueListingCell`.

in `awakeFromNib()`, set your

```
collectionView.delegate = self 
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

in `VenueListingCell` custom class,

Implement all `datasource` and `delegate` methods of `UICollectionView` in `VenueListingCell` custom class.

Let me know in case of any queries.